# Silverlight Navigation + Params?

Tags: c#, silverlight, navigation

I'm considering a scenario where I'd have a Silverlight 3 (or greater) application, which would utilize the SL Navigation framework.

Let us assume (for simplicity's sake) that it would be a simple forum. In my application I'd have a a page named `Forums.xaml`

Normally when I'd navigate to the said page the URL in the browser would change and the trailing string would match the page's name.

Normally it is possible to access a forum post by supplying the post's id in the url (to navigate directly to the forum post). Is such a thing possible in Silverlight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always, it depends on what specifically you're after.  If you just want to pull the query string value when you've landed on the page, use the dictionary supplied by NavigationContext.QueryString:

Assuming the page was called with the following Url:

```
mainFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml?Param=value", UriKind.Relative));
```

The resulting OnNavigatedTo override might look like this:

```
    // Executes when the user navigates to this page.
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("Param"))
        {
            paramText.Text = NavigationContext.QueryString["Param"];
        }
    }
```

Then it is up to you to adjust content on "Page1" based on the incoming parameter.

Now if you want to use Uri Mapping and clean up your Uri a bit, you can declare a UriMapper and hand it to your Navigation Frame, and use it to change your "clean" url into one that has a query string.

```
        <Navigation:UriMapper x:Key="PageMapper">
            <Navigation:UriMapping Uri="/Things/{value}" MappedUri="/Page1.xaml?Param={value}"/>
        </Navigation:UriMapper>
```

When called with:

```
mainFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/Things/newValue", UriKind.Relative));
```

will work with the same call listed above in OnNavigatedTo, with "newValue" passed as the query string (in your case, the Id) and the following appearing in the address bar:

'http://localhost:1877/SilverlightApplication3TestPage.aspx#/Things/newValue

Comment: This is an absolutely GREAT answer. Cheers